# C++ Separate an INT and Sum it's halves

Tags: c++

I want some logics or even code to show it to me.The problem is just as the title says.Example:
I enter n = 1234;
I separate n to 1 2 and 3 4,sum 1 and 2 and then sum 3 and 4 in two variables.
Then I compare the variables. I know how to separate the int,I know how to compare them,but I have no logic for the sum.How can I sum the two halves? Or even how can I separate those two halves? 
**Edit:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int getInput(string prompt)
{
    int val;
    cout << prompt;
    cin >> val;
    return val < 0 ? -val : val;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int num = getInput("Enter a number: ");
    cout << "Original Number: " << num << endl;

    stack<int> digits;
    int sum = 0;
    while(num > 0)
    {
        digits.push(num % 10);
        sum += digits.top();
        num = num / 10;
    }

    while(digits.size() > 0)
    {
        cout << digits.top() << " ";
        digits.pop();
    }

    cout << endl << "Sum of digits is " << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Okay.I got into this point.I can sum them up.How to separate the integer into two halves?

Comment: We are not a site where you can get free code for your homeworks. Please provide us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Please look at your comment.  Is it readable?  Please edit your post with code and compare to the code in your comment.

Comment: Please edit the question, and put code IN it

Comment: I am new,do not know how to.I am reading already. Will do.Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: BTW, the word *sum* means to *add*.  The C++ language has an operator, `+`, which can be used for sum and add.

Comment: Don't even think about the code right now.  First start off doing the problem with paper and pencil.  Once you solve it with that then convert that to pseudo code.  After that convert it to real code.

Comment: @NathanOliver - Okay.Will try to think over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us say that we have taken an integer, 1234, and split into two parts: 12 and 34:

```
int part_1 = 12;
int part_2 = 34;
```

To *sum* or *add*, we can use the addition operator:

```
int sum = part_1 + part_2;
cout << "Sum is: " << sum << endl;
```

**Edit 1:  Playing with digits**
In many cases when the requirements require manipulation of digits, keeping the number as text or a string is often easier.
Let us have a string:

```
  const std::string text_number = "1234";
```

We can obtain the length of the string:

```
const unsigned int length = text_number.length();
```

To split the string in half, we divide the length in half, then copy half of the characters to one string and half to another.

```
const unsigned int half_length = length / 2;
std::string part1;
std::string part2;
unsigned int index;
for (index = 0; index < half_length; ++index)
{
  part1 += text_number[index];
}
for (; index < length; ++index)
{
  part2 += text_number[index];
}
```

Now, the trick is to convert the text strings into internal number representation.  One method is to use `istringstream`;

```
std::istringstream stream1(part1);
std::istringstream stream2(part2);
int first_half;
int second_half;
stream1 >> first_half;
stream2 >> second_half;
```

Finally, they can be summed:

```
int sum = first_half + second_half;
```

Comment: I am okay.Thanks.I know how to improve the code.Thanks alot for showing me this method.

Comment: Looks correct, but why introduce costly int->string->int conversion and loops when you can get the # of digits via `ceil( log10( number ) )`?

Comment: @lorro:  The `log10()` function is also costly.  You'll have to pick your poison. :-)

Answer (score 1):

A lot of error handling missing, incl. checking whether the # of digits is even, but you'll get the point I think:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter your number: " << std::endl;

    int i = 0;
    std::cin >> i;

    int digits = (int) ceil( log10(i) );
    int modulo = pow(10, digits >> 1);
    std::pair<int, int> parts = { i / modulo,
                                  i % modulo };

    std::cout << parts.first << " " << parts.second << std::endl;
    int sum = parts.first + parts.second;
    std::cout << sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with.I improved Thomas' answer and came it up to a conclussion.It may be heavy method,but hey,it won't be professional showdown.Thanks for the method as well lorro and thank you for the feedback guys.Best Regards.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string text_number;
    std::cout << "Enter Number: ";
    std::cin>>text_number;
    const unsigned int length = text_number.length();  

    const unsigned int half_length = length / 2;
    std::string part1;
    std::string part2;
    unsigned int index;
    for (index = 0; index < half_length; ++index)
    {
      part1 += text_number[index];
    }
    for (; index < length; ++index)
    {
      part2 += text_number[index];
    }
    std::istringstream stream1(part1);
    std::istringstream stream2(part2);
    int first_half;
    int second_half;
    stream1 >> first_half;
    stream2 >> second_half;
    int S = 0,S1 =0;
    while(first_half>0)
    {
        int digit = first_half % 10;
        first_half /= 10;
        S += digit;
    }
        while(second_half>0)
    {
        int digit = second_half % 10;
        second_half /= 10;
        S1 += digit;
    }
    if(S > S1)
    {
        std::cout <<"First half half sum:" << S;
    }else {
        std::cout <<"second half sum:" << S1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```